# Is there a way to get the byte array for an image from ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, telerik

In my code, I have a `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.  I'd like to get that persisted to a byte array for saving to a database.  The image source is being returned by a library, so it's not available as a Stream, File, BitmapImage, or otherwise.

The library is the `Telerik.Windows.Documents.UI.ThumbnailFactory`.

Comment: Is this for the WPF or Asp.net Ajax Controls?

Comment: These are the Telerik controls for WPF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894170/how-to-convert-imagesource-to-byte-and-back-to-imagesource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894170/how-to-convert-imagesource-to-byte-and-back-to-imagesource)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  A BitmapSource is not the same as ImageSource.

Comment: Have a look at the very bottom of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/465372/Csharp-WPF-XAML-Convert-ImageSource-from-to-byte-a) codeproject thread.